# Removing unwanted characters from data

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have an array of numbers which formatted by a recursive function.

Here are the output numbers:

```
Â£15.00
Â£16.00
Â£22.30
Â£50.60
Â£44.00
Â£555.00
```

Now this A character at the beginning of each line. How can trim that away because ltrim() method just doesn't work on this occasion.

Comment: Maybe you should tweak the function instead. If it produces this output, it might not work well. What about sharing that?

Comment: Please print_r($arr) you and post output here for better understanding.  How special character messing with int value?

Comment: Why and how are you outputting that character in first place?

Comment: @user3035660 check my updated answer for remove only A

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `preg_replace()`?

```
preg_replace('/^Â£/','',$var);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters,

Comment: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str_replace('Â£', '', $var);
```

or

```
echo substr($var, 2);
```

or

```
echo preg_replace('/^Â£/','',$var);
```

For remove only `A`

```
str_replace('Â', '', $var);
```

or

```
echo substr($var, 1);
```

or

```
echo preg_replace('/^Â/','',$var);
```